# Java Copy ArrayList Value Not Reference

Tags: java

```
Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: " + loggedUserAuthResource.data.getUserPhotos());
List<UserPhoto> copiedList = loggedUserAuthResource.data.getUserPhotos();
copiedList.add(new UserPhoto("ADD"));
Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: " + copiedList);
Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: " + loggedUserAuthResource.data.getUserPhotos());
```

As you can see i just want to add an item to my copied list but it is also adding to loggedUserAuthResource list.

```
2019-08-18 15:06:18.104 8151-8151/ D/EditProfileActivity: onChanged: [UserPhoto{photoName='110ab4146695a093834701640fcee83c_y.jpg', orderId=1}, UserPhoto{photoName='59b7ee6ad3107d83227d017c45ffc899_y.jpg', orderId=2}, UserPhoto{photoName='90ae37db9a5d44026ebad8f622bf2c59_y.jpg', orderId=3}, UserPhoto{photoName='d2f7968640ebb4260b5e5dd1a10c1efd_y.jpg', orderId=4}, UserPhoto{photoName='e792f85d4f53a777f4399fe79f8edd99_y.jpg', orderId=5}, UserPhoto{photoName='22f943f0507223ce31fa1ca3c0e61b32_y.jpg', orderId=6}, UserPhoto{photoName='8b19b52c1482c522be21151eb4eb8009_y.jpg', orderId=7}]
2019-08-18 15:06:18.104 8151-8151/ D/EditProfileActivity: onChanged: [UserPhoto{photoName='110ab4146695a093834701640fcee83c_y.jpg', orderId=1}, UserPhoto{photoName='59b7ee6ad3107d83227d017c45ffc899_y.jpg', orderId=2}, UserPhoto{photoName='90ae37db9a5d44026ebad8f622bf2c59_y.jpg', orderId=3}, UserPhoto{photoName='d2f7968640ebb4260b5e5dd1a10c1efd_y.jpg', orderId=4}, UserPhoto{photoName='e792f85d4f53a777f4399fe79f8edd99_y.jpg', orderId=5}, UserPhoto{photoName='22f943f0507223ce31fa1ca3c0e61b32_y.jpg', orderId=6}, UserPhoto{photoName='8b19b52c1482c522be21151eb4eb8009_y.jpg', orderId=7}, UserPhoto{photoName='ADD', orderId=0}]
2019-08-18 15:06:18.104 8151-8151/ D/EditProfileActivity: onChanged: [UserPhoto{photoName='110ab4146695a093834701640fcee83c_y.jpg', orderId=1}, UserPhoto{photoName='59b7ee6ad3107d83227d017c45ffc899_y.jpg', orderId=2}, UserPhoto{photoName='90ae37db9a5d44026ebad8f622bf2c59_y.jpg', orderId=3}, UserPhoto{photoName='d2f7968640ebb4260b5e5dd1a10c1efd_y.jpg', orderId=4}, UserPhoto{photoName='e792f85d4f53a777f4399fe79f8edd99_y.jpg', orderId=5}, UserPhoto{photoName='22f943f0507223ce31fa1ca3c0e61b32_y.jpg', orderId=6}, UserPhoto{photoName='8b19b52c1482c522be21151eb4eb8009_y.jpg', orderId=7}, UserPhoto{photoName='ADD', orderId=0}]
```

Why is this happening? And how can i stop it?

Comment: What is `getUserPhotos()` doing? Can we see that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you don't copy anything :

```
List<UserPhoto> copiedList = loggedUserAuthResource.data.getUserPhotos();
```

You make the `copiedList` variable to refer to the same `List` instance as `loggedUserAuthResource.data.getUserPhotos()` refers to.

So it adds the object in the single `List` instance that exists :

```
copiedList.add(new UserPhoto("ADD"));
```

What you want is creating a new `ArrayList` object from the existing one (copy constructor).  In this way you have two distinct list objects and you can add the new element only in this new `ArrayList` :

```
List<UserPhoto> copiedList = new ArrayList<>(loggedUserAuthResource.data.getUserPhotos());
copiedList.add(new UserPhoto("ADD")));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to copy a list, I recommend using `Collections.copy`:

```
List<UserPhoto> copiedList = new ArrayList<UserPhoto>();
Collections.copy(copiedList, loggedUserAuthResource.data.getUserPhotos()); 
copiedList.add(new UserPhoto("ADD"));
```

Your `getUserPhotos()` method probably still references to the source list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer provided by [But I'm Not A Wrapper Class](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2498729/but-im-not-a-wrapper-class),would suffice. However, you could also do this.

```
List<UserPhoto> copiedList = new ArrayList<UserPhoto>();
copiedList.addAll(loggedUserAuthResource.data.getUserPhotos());
copiedList.add(new UserPhoto("ADD"));
```

Comment: 1. This will not even compile because `List` is an interface. 2. Why not just use copy constructor instead of creating new ArrayList and invoking `addAll`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @michalk. I was just offering another option of getting the same output.